# How to create an R dataframe from multiple JSON messages?

Tags: json, r

I have a data file in JSON format.  The following is a sample:

```
{"ts":"2018-01-04T02:19:05.144-06:00","ct":"{\"Antenna\":3,\"OlioId\":1,\"TagId\":\"30742C40A426936D4B681B3E\",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-01-04T02:19:05.144-06:00\"}"}
{"ts":"2018-01-04T02:19:05.167-06:00","ct":"{\"Antenna\":3,\"OlioId\":1,\"TagId\":\"307405B6E8538FED4B68F19F\",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-01-04T02:19:05.167-06:00\"}"}
{"ts":"2018-01-04T02:19:05.214-06:00","ct":"{\"Antenna\":4,\"OlioId\":1,\"TagId\":\"30742C40A426936D4B691D5D\",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-01-04T02:19:05.214-06:00\"}"}
{"ts":"2018-01-04T02:19:05.448-06:00","ct":"{\"Antenna\":6,\"OlioId\":1,\"TagId\":\"30742C40A42692ED4B67CD2E\",\"TimeStamp\":\"2018-01-04T02:19:05.448-06:00\"}"}
```

Using the `rjson` library I tried creating a dataframe but I can't get it to work out. I'm ending up with a list of two items `ts` and `ct`.

What I'd like to do is create a dataframe of the `ct` item with variable names `Antenna`, `OlioId`, `TagID`, and `TimeStamp`.

Can anyone give me their recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code you tried. Your objects only really have two columns, `ts` and `ct`. The `ct` value is a string that happens to look like json but it's not json. How did you get such an object in the first place? Looks like something went wrong earlier in the process.

Comment: You have newline delimited JSON. Use `ndjson::stream_in()` or `jsonlite::stream_in()` from the original file. Otherwise use `ndjson::flatten()` from an already read-in character vector.

Comment: hrbrmstr: Thank you.  ndjson is just what I was looking for.